# VBA multiple worksheet change events

Tags: excel, vba

VBA beginner here. I am trying to input a static timestamp in Column E based on the dropdown selection in column C, as well as a static timestamp in Column I based on the dropdown selection in Column G.

This seems to work if I only try and do one worksheet change - i.e. a static timestamp in Column E based on the dropdown selection in Column C - but breaks down when I try to add another.

When I delete the entry in Column C, also, the timestamp seems to remain. I would like deleting the Column C entry to trigger removing the timestamp if possible. I have pasted my current work below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

WORKING CODE (for 1 timestamp)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim MyTableRange As Range
Dim MyDateTimeRange As Range

Set MyTableRange = Range("C8:C70")

If Intersect(Target, MyTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set MyDateTimeRange = Range("E" & Target.Row)

If MyDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then

    MyDateTimeRange.Value = Now

End If

End Sub
```

ATTEMPTED CODE (for 2 separate timestamps)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim MyTableRange1 As Range
Dim MyDateTimeRange As Range

Set MyTableRange1 = Range("C8:C70")

If Intersect(Target, MyTableRange1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set MyDateTimeRange = Range("E" & Target.Row)

If MyDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then

    MyDateTimeRange.Value = Now

Else

Dim MyTableRange2 As Range

Set MyTableRange2 = Range("G8:G70")

If Intersect(Target, MyTableRange2) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set MyDateTimeRange = Range("I" & Target.Row)

If MyDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then

    MyDateTimeRange.Value = Now

End If

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
If Intersect(Target, MyTableRange1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

If you change a cell in `Range("G8:G70")`, you'll `Exit Sub` and never get to the second half of the code.

Try the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C8:C70,G8:G70"))

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
         On Error GoTo SafeExit
         Application.EnableEvents = False

         Dim cell As Range
         For Each cell In rng
             If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                 cell.Offset(,2).Value = Now
             Else
                 cell.Offset(,2).ClearContents
             End If
         Next
    End If

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```